# How to compare data value in all class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

consider the following case (simplification):

```
<li class='dest_list' data-selval='A'><span>1</span></li>
<li class='dest_list' data-selval='B'><span>2</span></li>
<li class='dest_list' data-selval='C'><span>3</span></li>
```

Now I want to check if a variable exist in any`li`. And I know I can do the following :

```
var needle = "D";
var found  = false;
$('.dest_list').each(function(){

       if($(this).data("selval") == needle)
           found = true;

});
```

But what I wonder is can I do that using a selector? Something like :

```
if($(('.dest_list').data("selval") == needle)
```

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: I was on this page at exactly the moment when a cascade of answers, edits, and upvotes came rolling in. It was neat to see the competitive nature of stackoverflow acting on what were essentially 4 identical answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
// Test for existence of element
if($(".dest_list[data-selval='D']").length) {
     // li with selval A exists...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted this one because of accurate link to documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the attribute in the selector like this

```
$('.dest_list[data-selval="D"]')
```

or if you want to use a variable you can do this

```
$('.dest_list[data-selval="' + needle + '"]')
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `attribute selector` to achieve that.

Try,

```
if($('.dest_list[data-selval="D"]').length > 0){
  //found
}
```